# Vuetify Vuex v-for v-switch default true

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I have a list of values in the Vuex store that I create v-switches for but I would like for the default value of the v-switch to be true on creation. I have tried `input-value="true"` but it does nothing. Any ideas how to set them to `true` since I can not find anything in the documentation that helps me?

```
<v-switch
        v-for="(layerg, k) in getAddedGeoMetLayers"
        :key="k"
        :label="layerg"
        :value="layerg"
        dense
        hide-details
        v-model="selectedGeometLayers"
        @change="updateSelectedAddedGeoMetLayers"
        ></v-switch>
```

```
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.selectedGeometLayers = this.getSelectedAddedGeometLayers
  },
  data () {
    return {
      selectedGeometLayers: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('map', [
      'getSelectedAddedGeometLayers'
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    updateSelectedAddedGeoMetLayers: function () {
      this.$store.dispatch('map/updateSelectedAddedGeometLayers', this.selectedGeometLayers)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `selectedValues` Array to equal the `getArray` - this way all the `v-switch` will be selected at the beginning:

```
mounted() {
    this.selectedValues = [...this.getArray]
}
```

Comment: I already did this, but the problem is when the component is mounted there are no switches and they only appear as the user adds them through another component. So i would need to move your solution to `watch` or `computed` no?

Comment: Yes, if you change the array of switches from another component add a watch to this array and update the selectedValues accordingly. A better solution is if you are using vuex to update the array of switches - add the selectedValues array to the store and when you add an item to switches array add it to the selectedValues array as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, it looks like you can set the model to have every item in your array.

From: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/switches/#model-as-array

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      people: ['John', 'Jacob'],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <p>{{ people }}</p>
      <v-switch
        v-model="people"
        color="primary"
        label="John"
        value="John"
      ></v-switch>
      <v-switch
        v-model="people"
        color="primary"
        label="Jacob"
        value="Jacob"
      ></v-switch>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```